# VB2008: Late bound resolution; runtime errors could occur

Tags: vb.net

I am using a Function that seems not compatible with VB strict option
It shoots a warning

***Late bound resolution; runtime errors could occur.***

```
    Public Function RegRead(ByVal Path As String) As String
        Dim ws As Object

        On Error GoTo ErrHandler
        ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        RegRead = ws.RegRead(Path)
        Return RegRead
        Exit Function

ErrHandler:
        RegRead = ""
    End Function
```

it sugests something related to "ws.RegRead"

[image]

Can someone tell me how to modify this to not have the warning ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you have

```
Dim ws As Object
```

This means that the compiler doesn't know what methods are available on `ws`, so all method calls will be late bound. Since the compiler can't check whether that method call is correct (name, parameter types are correct), this check happens at run-time. If anything is wrong then you will have a run-time error. With `Option Strict` it will give you a warning on that.

Instead you should use APIs designed for .NET, such as the [`Registry`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Comment: if I comment out that line I get a Error  that say "Name ws is not declared", lease be more verbose

Comment: Yeah, `Option Strict` requires that you declare things. This isn't a one-line fix, you should be using a modern API to access the registry.

Comment: The reason I am here is to learn new things.. This is why I would ask you to show me how to solve this.

Comment: The most valuable skills you can have as a programmer are: identifying a new path to solving a problem based on reading documentation/loosely related answers on stackoverflow and asking specific questions about the problems you're facing when you've already tried things yourself. Please read the documentation I linked to on the `Registry` class and make an effort yourself, then ask specific questions if you continue to run into problems. You will learn a lot more that way.